# Чем с linux передать контакты по bluetooth по протоколу PBAP

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Чем с linux передать контакты по bluetooth по протоколу PBAP (phone book access profile)?

Нужно название софта.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в сторону Wammu - должен быть в репозитории
или зайдите [СЮДА](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/hard/mobil-phone-on-Linux.html)

Comment: @Justicet это все не то. Старье. Просто передача файлов.

Comment: ну у меня-то передает контакты на SonyEricsson по голубому зубу и обратно